# How to remove all text except variable substring between two known points?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I've got a huge log file from our VPN appliance and I'd like to cut this down to simply the `Domain\Username`.  There is some variation of text after  `Domain\Username` but it all begins with the date (varies), time (varies), - Access-DC - (consistent), and a bracketed IP address (brackets remain but IP varies).  The username length also varies. Any help is appreciated.

Yeah, I'm pretty new to RegEx... I'm using Notepad++ to cut it down. Would like the text to appear as `Domain\username` at the end. I have tried several expressions to trim it down, but was only partially successful and since the text after `Domain\Username` varies it left many lines.

Ex. `.*(?<=Username:)` and `(?>,).*`

Sample Data:

```
2017-06-29 07:27:13 - Access-DC - [10.10.25.294] Domain\username(Basic Domain Access)[Basic Employee Access] - Web SSO: Authentication successful. Credential Used: Username: username, Error: (0) Initial, Realm: Domain.COM, Auth Type: (32) Kerberos, Cred Type: (0) System Credential, Target: server.Domain.com, Password: XXXXXX, Has Ticket: 1, Policy Auth: (32) Kerberos, Cred Label: Default, Server Realm: Domain.COM,

2017-06-29 07:27:13 - Access-DC - [10.5.27.236] Domain\username(Basic Domain Access)[Basic Employee Access] - Web SSO: Authentication successful. Credential Used: Username: username, Error: (0) Initial, Realm: Domain.COM, Auth Type: (32) Kerberos, Cred Type: (0) System Credential, Target: server.Domain.com, Password: XXXXXX, Has Ticket: 1, Policy Auth: (32) Kerberos, Cred Label: Default, Server Realm: Domain.COM,

2017-06-29 07:27:13 - Access-DC - [10.5.27.236] Domain\username(Basic Domain Access)[Basic Employee Access] - Web SSO: Authentication successful. Credential Used: Username: username, Error: (0) Initial, Realm: Domain.COM, Auth Type: (32) Kerberos, Cred Type: (0) System Credential, Target: server.Domain.com, Password: XXXXXX, Has Ticket: 1, Policy Auth: (32) Kerberos, Cred Label: Default, Server Realm: Domain.COM,
```

Desired Output:

```
Domain\username
Domain\username
Domain\username
```

Comment: What part you trying to trim, give an _after_ example. Looks pretty easy though. New to regex ?

Comment: Brand new to RegEx... I'm using Notepad++ to cut it down.  Would like the text to appear as Domain\Username at the end.  I have tried several expressions to trim it down but was only partially successful and since the text after Domain\Username varies it left many lines.  Ex. .*(?<=Username:) and (?>,).*

Comment: So effectively I'd like to go from this:  2017-06-29 07:27:13 - Access-DC - [10.10.25.294] Domain\username(Basic Domain Access)[Basic Employee Access] - Web SSO: Authentication successful. Credential Used: Username: username, Error: (0) Initial, Realm: Domain.COM, Auth Type: (32) Kerberos, Cred Type: (0) System Credential, Target: server.Domain.com, Password: XXXXXX, Has Ticket: 1, Policy Auth: (32) Kerberos, Cred Label: Default, Server Realm: Domain.COM,
To THIS: Domain\Username

Comment: So basically, you'd just get a count. In other words Domain\Username\nDomain\Username \nDomain\Username \n, etc.. ?

Comment: Well if it could be Domain\Username <new line> Domain\Username that would be optimal.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Try this, (globally) Find `(?s).*?(Domain\\Username)(?:(?!Domain\\Username).)*` replace `$1\r\n` Let me know if that works.

Comment: @AgentStuart Please add all new details to your question instead of adding via comments.  This will help readers to understand the full story without having to expand and read all of the comments.  (You are also meant to show what you've tried.)

Comment: Oh, you may want to set the case insensitive flag as well, or just stick it into the regex `(?is).*?(Domain\\Username)(?:(?!Domain\\Username).)*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Targeting the substring between `]` and `(`, this will get you there:

Pattern: `^[^]]+] ([^(]+).*`
Replace With: `$1`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nz2lSX/2)

Comment: @AgentStuart I've tested this to be accurate/successful on my Notepad++ using your provided data.  Is this what you are trying to do?  Your `Domain/username` substrings are, of course, not literal right?

Comment: YES!  That was a huge win... Thanks so much!